# not able to find the id of actionlink clicked

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem i need a jquery code to find which anchor tag-edit has been clicked in my jquery code. actually there are list of edit buttons so i need to find the the id of that particular button.

Thanks in advance 
Nilanjan Saha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out which Id has been clicked in the jquery click event.
let's say your buttons have a common class

```
<button id='one' type='button' class='my-edit-buttons'>button one</button>
<button id='two' type='button' class='my-edit-buttons'>button two</button>
<button id='thr' type='button' class='my-edit-buttons'>button thr</button>​
```

you can bind a click event to all of those buttons with the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('.my-edit-buttons').click(function(){
   var buttonClicked = $(this);
   var idOfButtonClicked = buttonClicked.attr('id');
   alert(idOfButtonClicked);
});
</script>
```

You can test this solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tjmehta/baXQJ/).

Answer (score 0):

Try with *$(this)* on the event function, i.e:

```
$("something").click(function() {
   var uid = $(this).attr('uid');
   ...
}
```